# AWS API gateway authorizer: Cognito + IP Whitelisting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Lets say I have an Admin API where I want to use Cognito to authenticate the user is in a specific group + from a whitelisted IP, how should I do that?

Am I right to say:

- I cannot use a Cognito authorizer since it only checks if the user is in a userpool and nothing more
- If I need to write a custom authorizer, I will need to follow https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-enhanced-request-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/ correct? I cannot use the IAM way to do IP whitelisting https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/04/14/amazon-api-gateway-ip-whitelisting/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For your use case, you need to use a Custom Authorizer which does the following,

- [Validation of Cognito Token](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/)
- Verify whether the Cognito User belongs to a particular group ([Or use Cognito UserPool Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html))
- Dynamically generate [API Gateway Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html) granting the authorized endpoints.
- Check the whitelisted IPs ([Need to allow Enhanced Request Headers to the Custom Authorizer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-enhanced-request-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/) to read the requester's IP). If there are only a few users who added manually and infrequently, along with their IP addresses, you can consider the Amazon API Gateway IP Whitelisting with a [Resource Policy](https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/04/14/amazon-api-gateway-ip-whitelisting/).